# I do not now why my form fails

Tags: php, html

I wrote this html and php code to send a form, but I do not understand why it fails.

my code :

**html**

```
 <form action="formulari.php" method="post">
             <p>
             Nombre:<input name= "name" type="text";>
             </p>
              <p>
             email:<input name= "email"  type="text";>
             </p>
             <p>Comentario:<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
             </textarea name= "message"></p>
             <input type="submit" value="enviar" >
             <input type="reset" value="borrar" >
         </form>
```

**php**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST [ 'name'];
$email = $_POST [ 'email'];
$message = $_POST['comentari'];
$to = "email@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Formulari_contacte";

mail ( $to, $subject, $message, $email);
header('Location: ../index.html?message=form_submitted');

?>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Do you have an error? What part of your code is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

HTML:

```
<form action="formulari.php" method="post">
    <p>Nombre: <input name="name" type="text"></p>

    <p>email: <input name="email" type="text"></p>

    <p>Comentario: <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message"></textarea></p>

    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    <input type="reset" value="borrar">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "email@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Formulari_contacte";

$mail = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $email);

// Check if email is send
if( $mail ) {
    header('Location: ../index.html?message=form_submitted');
} else {
    echo 'Email not send';
}
?>
```

I removed the ";" and unnecessary spaces in HTML and PHP. You also had the name of the textarea in the closing tag.

Also note that you are open for injection. Users are able to write some javascript code to you.

Comment: Please rectify your error. textarea name in html is message while in php script you are fetching value of textarea as comentari.

Comment: Now it sends me the email of the user but not the message

Comment: @Xalsar look at the comments and you I'll found out the error `$message = $_POST['message'];`

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze the html code, in that way you text area will miss the name.

You need to set the name of the text area in the opening tag

```
  <textarea name="comment">Enter text here...</textarea>
```

Plus your are using a different name in the server side, if you are using name ='message' you will need to use 'message' in to get the POST value

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_name.asp

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are unable to fetch textarea value

```
<form action="formulari.php" method="post">
    <p>Nombre:<input name= "name" type="text"></p>
    <p>email:<input name= "email"  type="text"></p>
    <p>Comentario:
        <textarea name= "comentari" rows="4" cols="50">
        </textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" >
    <input type="reset" value="borrar" >
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that answered my question, with your help and google i have made this formulary that has a anti-spam protection and a system to send the user to a page if the mail has been send.

HTML:

```
<form action="formulari.php" method="post">
    <p>Nombre: <input name="name" type="text"></p>

    <p>email: <input name="email" type="text"></p>

    <input name="edat" style=" display:none;">

    <p>Comentario: <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message"></textarea></p>

    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    <input type="reset" value="borrar">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "xavicarreragimbert@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Formulari_contacte";


if (!empty($_POST['edat'])){
    echo "Lo sentimos el sistema antispam ha detectado que es possiblemente un envio realizado a traves de spam";
    }

else{    
    mail( $to, $subject, $message, $email);
    header('Location: ../index.html?message=form_submitted');
    }   
    ?>
```